# URL Rewriting on static pages

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress blog with permalink. I created a static page which shows a table of products (www.abc.xx/database/). If a user clicks on one of the products, it opens a new static page named 'product' that retrieves and shows information about the product by its id from the database. The URL is www.abc.xx/database/product?id=1.

But I would like to have a URL like www.abc.xx/database/product/my-product instead of www.abc.xx/database/product?id=1? Could someone explains how it works?

**UPDATE:**

I played a little bit around with some solutions posted on blogs. I added the following snippet to my functions.php file.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('database/product/([^/]*)/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index .'index.php?pagename=product&product-name=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = 'product-name';
    return $aVars;
}
```

On the product page site I added

```
if(isset($wp_query->query_vars['product-name'])) {
echo urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['product-name']);
}
```

Now, if I call www.abc.xx/database/product/my-product, the product page opens but "my-product" is not shipped. The "product-name" var is not set. Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please check if the module `mod_rewrite` is available in the apache by checking the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Create a `.htaccess` in the directory that you're using.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ product?id=$1 [L]
```

For reference/guide, please visit http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: I had already tried your suggestion before I posted my problem here. Unfortunately, that procedure doesn't work with Wordpress.

Comment: @nullpointr See if this [Add mod_rewrite rules in WordPress](http://kovshenin.com/2009/adding-mod_rewrite-rules-to-htaccess-in-wordpress/) helps.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. It now works partially. I updated my first part where I describe my new problem where my parameter is not shipping through the pages. Any hint?